# UIView containing UIScrollView inside UITableViewCell's contentView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

I have made a simple UIView subclass I load from a nib, that I add as a subview to my custom cell's contentView. The view gets drawn and everything, but I am not allowed to scroll the scrollView I have inside my subclassed view.

```
[self.noteContentView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.noteContentView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100, 2000)];
[self.noteContentView setPagingEnabled:YES];
```

I have also disabled autolayout, which made it work as long as it wasn't inside a tableview cell's content view..

My guess is that the tableview "swallows" the touches before my scroller does. How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cellId"] autorelease];
    UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)] autorelease];
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)] autorelease];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000, 100);
    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

    [cell addSubview:view];
    [view addSubview:scrollView];

    return cell;
}
```

This just worked fine for me.

This is how I'm initing the table view

```
self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
```

Try to simplify your code until you can figure out what you're doing wrong.